# Overloading Base Class function

Tags: c++, c++11

Ok I have a class that wraps all WinAPI controls to make them operate like Java/C#/.Net controls (yes I know there are libraries that do this already) and looks like:

```
class Control
{
    public:
          //Bunch of other stuff..

        virtual HWND GetHandle() const;
};
```

and a derived class that looks like:

```
class MenuBar: public Control
{
    public:
        //Bunch of other stuff..

        virtual HMENU GetHandle() const;


        enum class Flags
        {
            POPUP = MF_POPUP, STRING = MF_STRING
        };
};
```

However, the compiler gives me an error about wrong return type for overloading the Base Class' GetHandle function.

How can I overload the `GetHandle` to have a different return type and to make it ignore the Base class's implementation? I really like the name `GetHandle()` and didn't want to change it (though that is an option)..

Is there another way? I'm asking because perhaps there is a way to make it forget that the base class has an implementation?

Comment: There is a way to make it forget the base implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
But it is not useful here, because I guess you want the derived versions to be called even if the object is referenced as Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *covariant return types*. The return type from the derived class needs to be a pointer or reference derived from the return type of the base class.

This can be accomplished by wrapping `HWND` and `HMENU` in a class hierarchy making a parallel of the API's organization. Templates may help if it's all generic.